# Vertical <ul> drop down from horizontal <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a basic drop-down menu. Whenever I however over "blog", the "wiki" link seems to get dragged into it.

Here's a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, "wiki" is below "march". I want to have "march" drop down from "blog" and keep "wiki" along the green line.

```css
#header {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 790px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 85%;
  background: #002929;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
#header li {
  display: inline;
}
#header ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#header ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#header a:hover {
  background: #0147FA;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffff4c;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    <li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="index.php">Home</a></strong></li>
    <li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></strong>
      <ul>
        <li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="march2015.php">March</a></strong></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="wiki.php">Wiki</a></strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/JugglingBob/zscwkzcb/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zscwkzcb/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mbrdp9tf/ is another solution which avoids absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

So I cleaned up the css and it seems to work now.
Here is your html below

```
<div id="header">
<ul>
<li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="index.php">Home</a></strong></li>
<li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></strong>
<ul>
<li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="march2015.php">March</a></strong></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li style="font-size:30px"><strong><a href="wiki.php">Wiki</a></strong></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the new css below:

```
#header {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 width: 790px; 
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 85%;
 background: #002929;
 word-spacing: 5px;
}

#header li {
 display: inline;
}

#header a:hover {
 background: #0147FA;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

#header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffff4c;
}

#header ul a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
}

#header ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#header ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    padding:0
}

#header ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

Be sure to compare to see the differences between your css and my css. If this is is not what you wanted please get back to me.